# Paint on a image (UIImageView) ipad application

Tags: ios, ipad, paint

How can implement paint canvas on a image by objective-c. It is only for illustrations, not for saving the image. It should be undone by shaking the iPad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you probably want to use a custom view which is on top of the UIView and overriding `drawRect:` and doing your drawing with CoreGraphics. here are a couple of tutorials that might help:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/2033/core-graphics-101-lines-rectangles-and-gradients
http://www.invasivecode.com/blog/archives/1033